# Can't append created SVG to div in D3 Vue3

Tags: d3.js, vuejs3

here is my SFC

i commented on the part that works well and doesn't work as well

```js
<template lang="pug">
.d3_simple
    h1 My D3 Vue3 Example
    svg(ref='svg_ref')
    hr
    div(ref='div_ref')
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

var svg_ref = $ref( null )
var div_ref = $ref( null )

// working
function d3_svg_ref()
{
    d3.select( svg_ref )
        .append( 'circle' )
        .attr( 'cx', 50 )
        .attr( 'cy', 50 )
        .attr( 'r', 25 )
        .style( 'fill', '#6fff00' )
}

// not working
function d3_div_ref()
{
    var svg = d3.create( 'svg' )
        .append( 'circle' )
        .attr( 'cx', 50 )
        .attr( 'cy', 50 )
        .attr( 'r', 50 )
        .style( 'fill', '#ffb300' )

    d3.select( div_ref ).append( svg )
}

onMounted(
    () =>
    {
        d3_svg_ref()
        d3_div_ref()
    }
)
</script>
```

getting an error `Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character`

ps: keywords > len 3 - shouldn't exist -- please don't bother to notice it

> It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

it's really silly, issue is pretty obvious without much talking ~_~

Answer (score 0):

GPT-3 do the job

```js
function gpt_fix1()
{
    var svg = document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg" )
    d3.select( svg )
        .append( 'circle' )
        .attr( 'cx', 50 )
        .attr( 'cy', 50 )
        .attr( 'r', 25 )
        .style( 'fill', '#ffb300' )
    d3.select( div_ref ).node().appendChild( svg )
}

function gpt_fix2()
{
    var svg = d3.create( 'svg' )
    svg.append( 'circle' ) // w/o "svg." not working
        .attr( 'cx', 50 )
        .attr( 'cy', 50 )
        .attr( 'r', 25 )
        .style( 'fill', '#4400ff' )
    d3.select( div_ref ).html( svg.node().outerHTML )
}

function gpt_fix3()
{
    var svg = d3.select( div_ref ).append( 'svg' )
    svg.append( 'circle' ) // "svg." is a key
        .attr( 'cx', 50 )
        .attr( 'cy', 50 )
        .attr( 'r', 25 )
        .style( 'fill', '#00ccff' )
}
```